# How to export Huge data of html table as a Excel file

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

This code is working fine for 5000 rows in chrome but when table exceed it's size more than 5000. Nothing is exported only in new tab shows #blocked

```
$("#exportDiv").click(function () {  
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87afc6'>";
    var textrange; var j = 0;
    tab = document.getelementbyid('reporttable'); // id of table
    for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerhtml + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }
    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, ""); 
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); 
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
    var ua = window.navigator.useragent;
    var msie = ua.indexof("msie ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.useragent.match(/trident.*rv\:11\./))      
    {
        txtarea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtarea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtarea1.document.close();
        txtarea1.focus();
        sa = txtarea1.document.execcommand("saveas", true, "report.xls");
    }
    else                 //other browser not tested on ie 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeuricomponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
});
```

Comment: It looks like if the `tab_text` is greater than 1.8 million characters it wont create the file. Probably a memory issue. I think this much data should handled in the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

The URL length that a browser can process is limited. It [depends on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/31250734#31250734), but for Chrome it currently is near the 32K limit. Given that some HTML characters get URL-encoded (like `&lt;`), an encoded HTML table row quickly takes 10 characters, so surely 5000 rows can exceed that browser limit.

Instead of putting the exported data on the URL, let a server-based application produce the content and return it with the proper HTML headers so it opens in a spreadsheet application.